# Queue Our Decomposition

Tags: code-golf, math, matrix, factoring

In this challenge I will ask you to find a QR decomposition of a square matrix.  The QR decomposition of matrix **A** is two Matrices **Q** and **R** such that **A = QR**.  In particular we are looking for **Q** to be an orthogonal matrix (that is **Q<sup>T</sup>Q=QQ<sup>T</sup>=I** where **I** is the multiplicative identity and **<sup>T</sup>** is the transpose) and **R** to be a upper triangular matrix (every value below its diagonal must be zero).

You will write code that takes a square matrix by any reasonable method and outputs a QR decomposition by any method.  Many matrices have multiple QR decompositions however you only ever need output one.

Elements of your resultant matrices should be within two decimal places of an actual answer for every entry in the matrix.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) competition so answers will be scored in bytes with fewer bytes being a better score.

---

#### Test Cases

*These are only possible outputs, your outputs need not match all of these as long as they are valid.*

```
0 0 0     1 0 0   0 0 0
0 0 0 ->  0 1 0   0 0 0
0 0 0     0 0 1 , 0 0 0

1 0 0     1 0 0   1 0 0
0 1 0 ->  0 1 0   0 1 0
0 0 1     0 0 1 , 0 0 1

1 2 3     1 0 0   1 2 3
0 3 1 ->  0 1 0   0 3 1
0 0 8     0 0 1 , 0 0 8

0 0 1     0 0 1   1 1 1
0 1 0 ->  0 1 0   0 1 0
1 1 1     1 0 0 , 0 0 1

0 0 0 0 1     0 0 0 0 1   1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0     0 0 0 1 0   0 1 1 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 ->  0 0 1 0 0   0 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 1 0     0 1 0 0 0   0 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1     1 0 0 0 0 , 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70880/discussion-on-question-by-wheat-wizard-queue-our-decomposition).

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 19 bytes

```matlab
@(x)[[q,r]=qr(x),r]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzOrpQpyjWtrAIyAYy/qdpREcb6hjpGMdaRxvoGOsYgmkDHYvYWM3/AA)

My first Octave answer \o/

Octave’s `qr` has quite a few alternatives in other languages that return both **Q** and **R**: `QRDecomposition` (Mathematica), `matqr` (PARI/GP), `128!:0` - if I recall correctly - (J), `qr` (R)...

Comment: So… will you post that J solution or shall I?

Comment: @Adám I won’t. Go ahead and post it if you want.

Comment: Why doesn't `128!:0` work on an all-zero matrix‽

Comment: [Does it work on all-zero matrices?](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzukJfo9S2sAjI1NQpjf2fphEdbaADhLHWaHSs5n8A "Octave – Try It Online")

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks a lot for the fix!

Comment: @Adám Fixed. Thanks for spotting that

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, 2 bytes

```
qr
```

The function `qr` accepts a square matrix and returns a `Tuple` of matrices: **Q** and **R**.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/8/Lb9IoSS1uEQhM09Boyq1KL9YwzOvREfBGIg0dRRSK1NR@NGGCkYKxtYKBgrGCoYgykDBIlaHSwEZRINEwZKGCgbWQAIIY4FagRoVTEB8I5CspYIpDq1w7QYwI6AMCBNsHsRgqJJYTbApBUWZeSU5eRqFRRogH2lqcqXmpfz/DwA)

Comment: Nice to see you! It doesn't get any shorter than this :-)

Comment: I knew you would come back shortly. Welcome back! What a built-in BTW...

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 15 bytes

```
QRDecomposition
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2Yb8z8wyCU1OT@3IL84syQzP@9/QFFmXkl0WnR1tYGOAhwZ1uooIAQMgSRCwBAiDBUwhCGwgCGKGbWxsf8B)

I mean... what can I say?

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```r
pryr::f(list(qr.R(q<-qr(m)),qr.Q(q)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvu/oKiyyMoqTSMns7hEo7BIL0ij0Ea3sEgjV1NTB8gN1CjU1NT8n2ubm1hSlFmhkaxhoGOgYwjGhhBaU8dYkysNqOE/AA)

Comment: You don’t need that space...? `pryr::f(list(qr.R(q<-qr(m)),qr.R(q)))`

Comment: [Does it work on all-zero matrices?](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvu/oKiyyMoqTSMns7hEo7BIL0ij0Ea3sEgjV1NTRwHC19TU/J9rm5tYUpRZoZGsYaCDBjV1jDW50oA6/gMA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @Adám Thanks, I had made a stupid typo. [Fixed now.](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvu/oKiyyMoqTSMns7hEo7BIL0ij0Ea3sEgjV1NTB8gN1CjU1NT8n2ubm1hSlFmhkaxhoIMGNXWMNbnSgBr@AwA "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda x:matrix(RDF,x).QR()
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>329</s> 324 bytes

```python
import fractions
I=lambda v,w:sum(a*b for a,b in zip(v,w))
def f(A):
 A,U=[map(fractions.Fraction,x)for x in zip(*A)],[]
 for a in A:
    u=a
    for v in U:u=[x-y*I(v,a)/I(v,v)for x,y in zip(u,v)]
    U.append(u)
 Q=[[a/I(u,u)**.5 for a in u]for u in U];return zip(*Q),[[I(e,a)*(i>=j)for i,a in enumerate(A)]for j,e in enumerate(Q)]
```

We must use fractions to ensure correct output, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#Numerical_stability

Indentation used:

1. 1 space
2. 1 tab

Comment: When indented you can save bytes by using `;` to separate lines.  You can also often forgo the line break after `:`.  I would suggest playing around with these because I can see a few places this answer can be shorter using this technique.

Comment: @WheatWizard Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for matrices with null rows.

Answer (score 0):

## Python with numpy, 28 bytes

```python
import numpy
numpy.linalg.qr
```